# GXT FramedPanel Drag for header

Tags: java, gwt, drag-and-drop, gxt

I want include Grid in FramedPanel and using gxt dnd.

But if I add FramedPanel in DragSource:

```
DragSource source = new DragSource(framedPanel) {
              @Override
              protected void onDragStart(DndDragStartEvent event) {
                super.onDragStart(event);
                event.setData(framedPanel);


              }
            };
```

DnD works when I click and hold on Grid.
How I can do to DnD only worked on the header of FramedPanel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using `Draggable` instead of `DragSource`, then use the constructor that takes two arguments. This way you can specify the header as the 'handle' argument.

```
Draggable draggable = new Draggable(framedPanel, framedPanel.getHeader());
//assuming GXT 3, just guessing from your post
draggable.addDragStartHandler(new DragStartHandler() {
  public void onDragStart(DragStartEvent event) {
    //...
  }
});
```

If you must use DragSource, subclass it to replace the Draggable instance, and create a new instance as specified above, plus making the changes found in the existing DragSource constructor.

Comment: Thanks It works.
I can register in Draggable few Drop Controller?